# php mysql get upcoming birthdays in 7 days dd-MMM-yy

Tags: mysql

in my family data table i have dob column with format like dd-MMM-yy. so i need to get upcoming 7 days birthdays from this data.
i ran query but not result showing... any solution ?

```
SELECT name, dob FROM persons  WHERE 
        DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), LEFT(dob, 8)))
                BETWEEN 
                DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                AND
                DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

The sample data are:

```
name        dob
prachi      09-Feb-15
badali devi 01-Jul-42
narayan ram 01-Jan-17
hasthi mal  01-Jan-18
bhiki devi  20-Jun-45
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). And please, never again provide a picture of text.

Comment: Store dates using a date data type, or don't bother using an RDBMS

Comment: *i have dob column with format like dd-MMM-yy* What is its datatype? some string type? convert it to DATETIME using STR_TO_DATE(). But the best solution is to alter the datatype.

Comment: @Akina its a varchar data type.. if possible give hint or query with this data type

Comment: I have already indicated which function to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM persons 
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d-%b-%y'))=MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d-%b-%y')) 
    BETWEEN DAY(curdate()) AND DAY(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 7 DAY) ;
```

Fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBaEMGygitjidzUBNMLJfz/5

Basically just turn the `dob` value into a standard MySQL date format using `STR_TO_DATE` and using somewhat similar to your `BETWEEN` operation.

More about [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

**EDIT:**

It appears that I didn't handle the overlapping months properly. In that case, I think of another way is to artificially append the person's birth date with current year and then use it to check  days interval. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE 
REPLACE(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d-%b-%y'),YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d-%b-%y')),YEAR(CURDATE())) 
BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE()+INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solved your issue @kamleshrathore . thank you

Comment: What do you mean its not working? Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62445757/edit) and include the part where its not working? Thanks

Comment: i edited question with data.. its not working for person name "badali devi 01-Jul-42"

Comment: What is you MySQL Version?

Comment: regardless the mysql version its not working even your  given fiddle also https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBaEMGygitjidzUBNMLJfz/5

Comment: That's my mistake. I haven't change the data in table for `bavali devi`.. it was still "01-Jan-42". Look at this updated fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBaEMGygitjidzUBNMLJfz/6